# Using an external drive from Seagate with an HDD from Samsung

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

I have been running my external drive Seagate STBV20002004.5 for 2.5 years until it started showing read errors. I disassembled it and replaced the HDD with a Samsung HD501LJ (which, I am sure, is functional). After I reassembled the drive, Linux wouldn't detect it upon connection.

`dmesg`:

```
[ 3278.581016] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 3278.697200] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=3312
[ 3278.697204] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3278.697207] usb 1-6: Product: Expansion Desk
[ 3278.697209] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: Seagate 
[ 3278.697212] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: NA4LKLZQ
[ 3278.697472] usb-storage 1-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3278.697816] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-6:1.0
[ 3279.697820] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion Desk   0319 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 3279.698381] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 3287.367997] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 3287.374070] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3287.374074] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[ 3287.374091] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 3287.374096] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[ 3287.374116] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[ 3287.374118] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3287.374332] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3287.374335] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[ 3287.374349] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Is there anything I can do to make it work?

Comment: Maybe the enclosure is bad, not the hard drive.

Comment: It's possible that the enclosure has failed like @moab mentioned. I'd advise you to try connecting the new HDD internally via SATA or use a SATA-to-USB cable (could also be a docking station) to see if you'd be able to access it properly. However, I'm afraid you won't be able to fix the enclosure itself, so I'd recommend you to consider replacing it. Best of luck! :)